# Swift 3: replace c style for-loop with float increment

Tags: ios, swift

I have such a loop in my app:

```
for var hue = minHue; hue <= maxHue; hue += hueIncrement
{
   let randomizedHue = UIColor.clipHue(
       Random.uniform(ClosedInterval(hue - dispersion, hue + dispersion))
   ) 
   colors.append(colorWithHue(randomizedHue))
}
```

`hueIncrement` is **float**, so I cant use range operators like this: `..<`.

**What is the best and the most neat way to implement such loop in Swift 3?**

Comment: something like `for hue in (minHue).stride(through: maxHue, by: hueIncrement){...}`

Comment: You right! Can you post an answer, so I can close this question, please?

Comment: You shouldn't use for loops with Float anyway, because of loss of precision.

Comment: @gnasher729, precision is not important in this case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use stride function `stride(through:, by:)` for this .. something like

```
for hue in (minHue).stride(through: maxHue, by: hueIncrement){
    // ...
}
```

From `Swift3.0`, you can use `stride(from:to:by:)` or `stride(from:through:by:)` syntax

```
for hue in stride(from: minHue, through: maxHue, by: hueIncrement){
    //....
}
```