# C-style statement is going to be depreciated for var i loop

Tags: swift

I have search a bit online but being new to Swift, I couldn't find anything that helped me convert a for loop to the upcoming Swift version.

I have this

```
for var i: CGFloat = start; i <= stop; i += step {
```

and trying to convert to the new format but unsure how.

Can someone please help before my code stops working?

Thanks :)

Comment: Use 'stride' keyword..!! ;)

Comment: ah right. got it! THanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173379/warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-ve/36173489#36173489

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469753/swift-3-replace-c-style-for-loop-with-float-increment/36469912#36469912

Answer (score 0):

```
  for i in number.stride(through: toSecondNumber, by: withStep)
```

**where** i - name for you variable

**number** - start value of i

**secondNumber** - lastValue of range

**withStep** - step of iteration

you can you **through** to include last value or **to** to exclude last value

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'stride' keyword.

More info about your [solution](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html).